# Is it possible to have proof of stake and proof of work transactions in the same block ?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, proof-of-stake

To understand more of the blockchain technology i asked myself , is it possible to have proof of stake and proof of work transactions in the same block ?

Comment: What system/blockchain are you asking about? Bitcoin doesn't have PoS, and Pow only applies to blocks as a whole (transactions individually don't have PoW).

Comment: I asked because there are some hybrid blockchains who uses POW and POS mecanism and i want to understand how they get stored in the blockchain. POS blocks + POW blocks or mixed Blocks ? could be that there is a fundamental thing that i dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of Stake and Proof of Work are two strategies of arriving at consensus. I'm not aware that the transaction format would need to be impacted whatsoever by having one or the other in play.